# Ltspice2matlab error: Bad tag name found!

Tags: ltspice, matlab

Hi I want to convert the raw data generated from LTspiceXVII to variables in Matlab. I am using the LTSpice2Matlab function.`data= LTspice2Matlab('netlist_whole_network.raw')`. But I get Format error in LTspice file "C:\Users..netlist_whole_network.raw" ... Bad tag name found! Could you help me diagnose the source of the error? Also, what is a tag?

Comment: What does the help for the `.m` file say? As it is, I doubt anyone can tell you what is wrong since you don't give a link for the script (it could be in a different location than usual -- even though I don't know where this "usual" is), or the error is truncated and that's how you show it (it could be that you have special characters), or there is an I/O error, or...

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, I am running the following script: [https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23394-fast-import-of-compressed-binary-raw-files-created-with-ltspice-circuit-simulator?focused=5113448&tab=function]. I input my netlist_whole_network.raw file generated from LTspiceXVII in the function. The file is created in the same folder as the LTSpice2Matlab function. But I get an error at line 205 if you copypaste it in a Matlab editor, '' Format error in LTspice file "C:\Users..netlist_whole_network.raw" ... Bad tag name found''.

Comment: "To submit or download files, sign in to your MathWorks Account or create a new one." This prevents me from downloading, and showing the contents might be against the license, so I cannot help you. But what does the help say? If you run `help LTspice2Matlab` what does it say? Maybe you don't use quotes? (as in `'filename'`, not `filename`)?

Answer (score 2):

LTspice XVII changed the .raw file format and now encodes text as UTF-16 instead of ASCII, which the original LTspice2Matlab script can't handle. A modified version can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/PeterFeicht/ltspice2matlab), it also supports a number of additional simulation types.

Comment: Hello @Pezo and thank you for your Github update of the LTspice2Matlab function. The extraction of the .ac values goes so smooth, unlike the .trans simulation which yields weird waveforms, which when compared to those seen in the LTspice GUI are kind of a mess. Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong and how I can fix it? Thanks in advance